# Add an external HTML file into an existing HTML page

Tags: html, forms

I have a large website which has a hand full of forms, each of these forms are displayed many times over across many different pages, so in to make the future editing and updating of these forms easy, I want to create each form as a HTML file which is then pulled into the applicable pages using minimal code, so that each form will only need to be changed once and it will be updated across the site automatically.

These forms are also responsive, so I don't think an iframe is the best solution?

Thanks in advance
Willem

Comment: ok, sounds great, what is your question exactly? and what language are you running on, php, java, python, ruby, ASP.Net?

Comment: Sorry, my question is: how can one add an external HTML file into an existing page? This is on a Wordpress site, so that would be php.

Comment: `include()` will do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On WordPress you create a part template from your form e.g. form1.php in your theme folder. Then you can put this in your template with:

```
get_template_part( 'form1' );
```

On WordPress a good solution for forms is [Contact Form 7](http://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/) which will give you more flexibility with including the forms on your pages instead of fixing the form in the templates.

Comment: Thanks Michelle, I'm going to give this a try. I'm aware of Contact Form 7, I'm currently using Gravity Forms, but I'm switching to Google forms (which outputs code that I need to add to the site) because it pulls the data directly into a Google spreadsheet rather than a database, which will be invaluable to my client.

Comment: Unfortunately 'get_template_part' adds the form as the first item on the page rather than adding it where I've placed the code.

Comment: It's hard to know without seeing the resulting page and the templates but that's not the expected behavior. I would check the resulting html structure is valid. I would also check that only the part between the form tags is included in the sub-template.

Comment: You might be able to try this WordPress Google Forms plugin if it makes life easier https://wordpress.org/plugins/wpgform/. That removes the html wrapper code automatically and you can use a shortcode to insert the form.

Comment: Hi Michelle, I've actually already resorted to this, but now I've got another problem, there seems to be no way to change the text on the Submit button, but I'll post this question on the webapps stackexchange. Thanks for all the help :)